# Postgresql excluding already existing friendships relations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: **Users** and **friendships**:

```
CREATE TABLE t_users (
user_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar
);

CREATE TABLE t_friendship (
friendship_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
from_user_id varchar,
to_user_id varchar
);

INSERT INTO t_users VALUES ('us123', 'us123');
INSERT INTO t_users VALUES ('us456', 'us456');
INSERT INTO t_users VALUES ('us789', 'us789');
INSERT INTO t_users VALUES ('us987', 'us987');
INSERT INTO t_users VALUES ('us654', 'us654');
INSERT INTO t_users VALUES ('us321', 'us321');

INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr123', 'us123', 'us456');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr456', 'us123', 'us789');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr789', 'us123', 'us987');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr987', 'us456', 'us123');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr654', 'us456', 'us321');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr321', 'us987', 'us123');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr322', 'us456', 'us654');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr323', 'us654', 'us123');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr324', 'us789', 'us654');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr325', 'us321', 'us123');

SELECT 
t_users.user_id, 
t_users.name
FROM  t_friendship
inner join t_users on t_friendship.from_user_id = t_users.user_id
WHERE t_friendship.to_user_id = 'us123';
```

[Work example](http://rextester.com/live/AJW38427)

How to make a request that will show the recommended friends, while **excluding** already **existing** friendships relations (from_user_id -> to_user_id)? For example **'us123', 'us456'**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular results, you would use:

```
select u.*
from t_users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from t_friendships f
                  where f.to_user_id = 'us123' and
                        f.from_user_id = u.user_id 
                 ) and
      u.user_id <> 'us123';
```

SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/06dac/3).

More commonly, friendships are symmetric -- meaning that if a/b are friends, then so are b/a.  If this general rule is true, you can do:

```
select u.*
from t_users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from t_friendships f
                  where f.to_user_id = 'us123' and
                        f.from_user_id = u.user_id 
                 ) and
      u.user_id <> 'us123';
```

If you want to preclude friend suggests in either direction, use `not exists` twice:

```
select u.*
from t_users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from t_friendships f
                  where f.to_user_id = 'us123' and
                        f.from_user_id = u.user_id 
                 ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t_friendships f
                  where f.from_user_id = 'us123' and
                        f.to_user_id = u.user_id 
                 ) and
      u.user_id <> 'us123';
```

This query will return no rows because the user has friends (in some direction) with all other users.

Note that if you are calling this from an application, then you should be using parameters rather than stuffing the user id in to the query string.

Comment: Oh sure. Your last example returns an empty result. And the first one works as it should. Which option is preferable?

Comment: @SergeyKozlov . . . I misunderstood the data.  The friendships are not symmetric.  I modified the answer with the version that gives the results you want.

Comment: @SergeyKozlov . . . Not for the first query.  The results depend on whether the friendship relationship is symmetric, which is what the rest of the answer attempts to explain.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon. Your answers are true and inspirational. Thank you for the allotted time.